# Finding vertical asymptotes of $\frac{3x^4 + 3x^3 - 36x^2}{x^4 - 25x^2 + 144}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find the vertical asymptotes for $$f(x) = \frac{3x^4 + 3x^3 - 36x^2}{x^4 - 25x^2 + 144}$$

If I understand correctly, the vertical asymptote exists at $x=a$ when a value $a$ is found such that $f(a)$ increases to $∞$.

So, we must find a number that is infinitely small on the denominator, or in other words, $0$.

Setting $$x^4 - 25^2 + 144 = 0$$

$$(x^2 - 9)(x^2 - 16) = 0$$
$$(x+3)(x-3)(x+4)(x-4) = 0$$

So based on my understanding, $[-4, -3, 3, 4]$ should be values of $a$ where $x = a$ is a vertical asymptote.

Graphing this function, I can clearly see that there are only vertical asymptotes at $x = 4$ and $x = -3$.

Where did I go wrong in my theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values of $x$ that make the denominator zero (in this case $3,-3,4,-4$) are the *candidates* for vertical asymptotes.

You also need to see what values of $x$ make the numerator zero.  If both are zero then it is possible you have a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Removable_discontinuity), not an asymptote.  For example, consider $$\frac{x-2}{x-2}$$

Comment: Got it. So if I understand correctly, my process is correct, however I need to add the steps required to verify for removable singularity, once I have the asymptote candiates?

Comment: You have correctly done the first part of the problem, now you need to do the second part.

Comment: nice................+1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

By factoring the numerator we have
\begin{align}
3x^4+3x^3-36x^2&=3x^2(x^2+x-12)\\
&=3x^2(x+4)(x-3)
\end{align}
Then 
$$\frac{3x^4+3x^3-36x^2}{x^4 - 25x^2 + 144}=\frac{3x^2(x+4)(x-3)}{(x+3)(x-3)(x+4)(x-4)}=\frac{3x^2}{(x+3)(x-4)}\qquad x\neq -4, x\neq 3$$
So, the limit of the function when $x\to -4$ and $x\to 3$ are finite, hence no asymptotes are at these points.

Comment: Wow, yes, this is the optimal factorization, however it does not address why my suboptimal factorization failed.

Comment: @EricJohnson I think that your factorization is not the problem, cause you should also consider the numerator in order to conclude about which are asymptotes.